# Can a child class implement the same interface as its parent?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, implementation

I've never encountered this issue before today and was wondering what convention/best practice for accomplish this kind of behavior would be.

Basic setup is this:

```
public interface IDispatch {
    void Dispatch();
}

public class Foo : IDispatch {
    void IDispatch.Dispatch() {
        DoSomething();
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo {
     ...
}
```

Bar needs to subclass Foo because it shares all the same properties as Bar plus introduces 2 new ones that I need to encounter for. The problem I have is that Foo also needs a slightly different implementation of Dispatch(). Normally it would be overridden but thats not valid for an interface method so is it fine to just have Bar implement IDispatch as well so my class definition looks like this:

```
public class Bar : Foo, IDispatch { .... }
```

and then just do an explicit implementation of that interface method in Bar as well? My compiler doesn't seem to complain when I try to do it this way but I wasn't sure if it would cause any runtime issues resolving which implementation to use down the road or if there was a better way to accomplish something like this.

Also worth mentioning that at my workplace we use code generation from UML models which enforces that all class design must be done from a model first. The code generation tool is what causes interface methods to be implemented explicitly (don't want to debate the pros and cons of this its just what I'm forced to deal with right now so having an implicit implementation is not an option)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could, alternatively, do this one of two ways:

First, don't implement the interface explicitly:

```
public class Foo : IDispatch {
    public virtual void Dispatch() {
        whatever();
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo {
    public override void Dispatch() {
        whateverElse();
    }
}
```

Second, implement it explicitly but add a function that the child class can override:

```
public class Foo : IDispatch {
    void IDispatch.Dispatch() {
        this.Dispatch();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispatch() {
        whatever();
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo {
    protected override void Dispatch() {
        whateverElse();
    }
}
```

Comment: in your "Second" comment - you mean derived instead of base, no?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can explicitly redeclare that you want to implement `IDispatch`, and implement it explicitly again in `Bar`.

**However**, you won't be able to call the original implementation in `Foo`. If you need to do that, you'll need to change `Foo` either to use implicit interface implementation with a virtual method (which can be overridden and then called with `base.Dispatch()` in `Bar`) or make the `Foo` implementation call a protected virtual method which again you'd override in `Bar`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jon. Just to be clear, Bar will never need to use Foo's implementation of Dispatch and vice versa. So in this case I should be fine given that they only care about their own implementation?

Comment: @JesseCarter: No, because an instance of `Bar` *is* an instance of `Foo`. Do you **really, really** not want the implementation in `Foo` to be called when a client calls `Dispatch` on an instance which is a `Bar`? If so, should `Bar` really be derived from `Foo` in the first place? (It's unusual - though not unheard of - to *completely* replace an implementation like that.)

Comment: A special intersting case is that you can let a derived class implement a method that was declared in the base class not implementing the interface: `class A { public void Dispatch() {} }` `class B : A, IDispatch { }`. (almost a corner case)

Comment: @JonSkeet I cannot see any situation in which I would need Foo's implementation to be called when dealing with Bar. IDispatch are queued up in the system and when grabbed by a worker thread they call Dispatch which executes whatever code that class represents. If a Bar is dequeued I want it's implementation of Dispatch to be called not the implementation in its parent

Comment: @JesseCarter: Again, that sounds like `Bar` probably shouldn't derive from `Foo` in the first place then.

Comment: That very well could be, it just seemed like in this specific case Bar is a Foo given its properties and what it represents in the system so it seemed like unnecessary code duplication to have the 2 classes that were so similar

Comment: @JesseCarter: Perhaps you should use composition instead of inheritance then - perhaps `Bar` should *contain* a `Foo` for the purpose of sharing implementation, but not try to pretend that it will *act* like a `Foo`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmmm thats another great idea although I am leaning towards the second implementation mentioned by Rawling as it allows for the Dispatch method to be propery overridden by the child while preserving an explicit implementation of Dispatch in the parent

Answer (score 4):

Bar already implements IDispatch if it is subclass of Foo, no need to explicitly state that. If you want to implement only one method of interface in a different way, do sth like this:

```
IDispatch { void Method(); }
Foo : IDispatch { public virtual void Method() { implementation1 } }
Bar : Foo { public override void Method() { implementation2 } }
```

Comment: Check the edit I made to my original post. This looks nice but I am unable to do it this way right now due to coding standards at my workplace

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do the `IDispatch.Dispatch` - so long as a method called `Dispatch` is in your class you will have implemented the interface.

You can do this, it builds for me:

```
  public class Foo : IDispatch
  {
    public virtual void Dispatch()
    {
    }
  }
  public class Bar : Foo
  {
    public override void Dispatch()
    {
      base.Dispatch();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Check the edit I made to my original post. This looks nice but I am unable to do it this way right now due to coding standards at my workplace

Comment: @JesseCarter Rawlins answer looks like what your looking for, call an expose virtual method which isn't explicit to the interface and then override that

Comment: Yah I am leaning towards that too. Seems like the cleanest solution given what I'm dealing with

Answer (score 0):

I do prefer to explicitly implement interfaces. It's easier for people unfamiliar with your code base to understand what's an interface vs class specific logic.

You can still accomplish class inheritance while explicitly implementing interfaces. You just need to have the base class implement the interface, and have that implementation call into a virtual function which can be extended. Here's an example:

```
interface Inter
{
    void Call();
}

class A : Inter
{
    //Explicitly implemented interface
    void Inter.Call()
    {
        this.Call();
    }

    public virtual void Call() { Console.WriteLine("Base call in A"); }
}

class B : A
{
    public override void Call()
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Called B" );
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var a = new A();   //Base class
        var aa = (Inter)a; //Interface only
        a.Call();
        aa.Call();

        var b = new B();   //Child class
        var bb = (Inter)b; //Interface only of Child class
        b.Call();
        bb.Call();

        //See the output before the console program closes
        Console.ReadLine();         
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
Base call in A
Base call in A
Called B
Called B
```